# Problem with the controller, 404 the route doesnt exist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, java-ee-8

i have a problem with the controller

[image]

with this URL
http://localhost:8080/hello

My controller settings are this

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello dev";
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/createuser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto){
        try {
            UserDto createdUserDto = userService.createUser(userDto);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUserDto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

when i started my Spring application this is the port i have 8080

```
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:51.104+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.m.g.GestionUsuariosApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting GestionUsuariosApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 41768 (C:\Users\luis_\MadridSeguros\GestionUsuarios\target\classes started by luis_ in C:\Users\luis_\MadridSeguros\GestionUsuarios)
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:51.106+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.m.g.GestionUsuariosApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:51.421+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:51.434+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:51.961+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:51.969+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:51.970+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.056+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.057+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 910 ms
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.165+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.209+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.352+02:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.orm.deprecation           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.447+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.688+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2bb31455
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.690+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.738+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mSQL dialect                             [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.979+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:52.988+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:53.046+02:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mJpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:53.333+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2023-04-06T02:44:53.340+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.m.g.GestionUsuariosApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started GestionUsuariosApplication in 2.534 seconds (process running for 3.014)
[2m2023-04-06T02:48:14.151+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-04-06T02:48:14.151+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2023-04-06T02:48:14.152+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m41768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

Am i doing anything wrong? because i dont know if im miss configuring the controller and i keep getting this whitelabel error page ¿Any ideas?

Comment: probably due to the the controller class is excluded during component scanning. What is the package name of `UserController` class and `GestionUsuariosApplication` class?

Comment: there is the package com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios, the applications main its inside and then there is com.madridseguros.gestionusuarios.controller

Answer (score 0):

Have you given any vlaue to server.servlet.contextPath property in application.properties file. If yes the your endpoint will be like http://localhost:8080/{contextPath}/hello